# Find out what my bluetooth identifier is?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, bluetooth

Once bluetooth discoverability is enabled, the device will be broadcasting a unique 48-bit identifier, right? What code can I use to find out the value of that identifier?

I'd trying to make a cross-platform app that will need to find out what the phone's own bluetooth identifier is. So if you know how to do that for iOS or android etc, that would be great a start. Or if its possible with javascript, that might be ideal, as I'll be using phonegap to translate the app as a whole for the multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PhoneGap bluetooth plugin for Android [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Bluetooth).  I don't see any APIs for getting the identifier, but it might be a start ....